# mysql query excluding a set of data but includindg certain items from the set if item contains value in a specific column

Tags: sql, mysql

I need to exclude a product line from a database so I do pline != prodctline but certain products in that product line I do not want to be excluded. 
For instance:
here is simlplistic version of my database:

partname, pline, option  (3 columns)

i want to exclude all results from a certain product line unless they have X option value.
soo

part name, product line, option

widget1  10   null

widget2  10   option1

widget3  10   option5

widget4  10   option2

so i might want to exclude all of product line 10 unless it comes with option 1.

or

i might want to exclude all of product line 10 but unless it comes with option 1 and option 2.

Hope this helps

I'm not sure how to go about doing this in a query. Is there a sql clause that I'm not aware of?

I was trying to do it with where pline != 90 and option = 'option1' but that was not working.

Thanks

Comment: Simple logic - pline<>10 or (pline=10 and option='option1'); no sql knowledge involved.

Comment: What does the <> symbol mean next to pline?

Comment: <> is the same thing as != in SQL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Actual Answer

I want all info about all products that have a product line other than 10.  I also want the ones that have a product line of 10 but also have an option of "option1" or "option2".  Here's how I express that:

```
select part_name, product_line, option 
from products 
where product_line <> 10 or option = "option1" or option = "option2";
```

The <> means not equal to.  I say it's not equal to 10 or it's option 1 or it's option 2.  If a row matches any of this criteria, it's accepted.

---

### One step further...

Let's try something more complicated.  Let's say you want all products with a product line less than 10.  But you also want all the products with a line of exactly 10 (not 11 or 12, etc) that have an option of "option1" or "option2".  In this example, the fact that the product line = 10 becomes important for option1 and option2.

```
select part_name, product_line, option
from products
where 
  product_line < 10 
  or 
  (product_line = 10 and (option = "option1" or option = "option2"));
```

With a combination of ands, ors, and parentheses, you can be very specific about what you are selecting from the database.

Comment: Didn't know that <> represented not equal to. I've always used the != to represent not equal to.

The answer is perfect, thanks